# Android App - Google maps android API V2 marker locations - Logcat error

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There are no errors in the program while i compile. But when its running there are log cat errors and application gets crashed.

Note: I didnt generate a API key is it must to put my own api key .i have used api key that i found from the tutorial that i refer to build this app.

This is my Log cat

```
12-23 14:56:49.560: W/dalvikvm(10858): Unable to resolve superclass of Lin/wptrafficanalyzer/locationmarkermysql/MainActivity; (6)
12-23 14:56:49.560: W/dalvikvm(10858): Link of class 'Lin/wptrafficanalyzer/locationmarkermysql/MainActivity;' failed
12-23 14:56:49.570: D/AndroidRuntime(10858): Shutting down VM
12-23 14:56:49.570: W/dalvikvm(10858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a58ba8)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858): Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql, PID: 10858
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql-1, /system/lib]]
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql-1, /system/lib]]
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
12-23 14:56:49.660: E/AndroidRuntime(10858):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
    <permission 
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!--  Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) 
    to determine the device's location to within a very small area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

     <!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY" />      


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you included the external jar files in the libs folder?

Comment: @gerardnimo yes i have included